# given a list of list return the list of integer values from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

given a list

```
lt=[1,2,[3,[5,[6,[7]]]]]
```

I know this is a basic question and I have done it with for loops but, I need to understand how this basic question can be done in a single or two lines. This was asked to me in an interview.

```
return [1,2,3,5,6,7]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Comment: are you sure it's only two lines?
With recursion you might do something with two lines, but then you had to call the declared function, which would be a third line.
You see for example an answer from DarryG, but ut us using three lines and not two.
two lines do ceclare the function and one to call it.

Comment: @bencv: Yes in fact this is a duplicate. One of the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists  uses only  two lines (or one with ';')

It's Statham's answer.

However reduce is no more a predeclared function in python3, so one had to add some imports to the line

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version of @DarrylG's solution, helping to get the line count down.

```
flatten = lambda lst: sum((flatten(v) if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for v in lst), [])
flatten(lt)
```

Lambda functions can be recursive, but are one line shorter then function declarations.

And this could also be in one line by using a `;`

```
flatten = lambda lst: sum((flatten(v) if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for v in lst), []) ; flatten(lt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to flatten recursively.

### Solution

```py
# Custom function
def get_flatlist(l, flat_list=None, no_more_list_elements = True):
    if flat_list is None:
        flat_list = list()

    for x in l:
        if isinstance(x,list):        
            flat_list += x
            no_more_list_elements = no_more_list_elements & False
        else:
            flat_list.append(x)
            no_more_list_elements = no_more_list_elements & True
    #print(no_more_list_elements)
    if not no_more_list_elements:        
        flat_list = get_flatlist(flat_list.copy(), 
                                 flat_list=None, 
                                 no_more_list_elements = True)
    return flat_list    

get_flatlist(lt)
```

**Output**:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

### Data

```py
lt=[1,2,[3,[5,[6,[7]]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Method to flatten lists of lists (1-2 line function)
(mod of [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists))

1. Use a generator to create single element lists
2. Use sum to append these into a single list

```
def flatten(lst):
    return sum( ([x] if not isinstance(x, list) else flatten(x)
                 for x in lst), [] )
```

lt=[1,2,[3,[5,[6,[7]]]]]

print(flatten(lt))

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```